# Ember data single data extract through browser URL

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Getting all articles is ok, but when try to retrieve just one article through route url directly, system error - undefined

```
var articles = Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost/emberdata/api/articles');
```

will return:

```
[{"articles":
   [
     {
        "id":1,
        "title":"Ember is the best",
        "author":"brk","excerpt":"Programming is awesome"
     },
     {
        "id":2,
        "title":"Backbone not a framework",
        "author":"krb",
        "excerpt":"Server-side controller sucks"
     },
     {
        "id":3,
        "title":"Javascript pwned",
        "author":"rbk",
        "excerpt":"I know right"
     }
  ]
}]
```

API is created using PHP Slim Rest API

this Route working find, showing all the data in the handlebar template

```
App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
      return articles;
   }
});
```

However for child view routing, undefined is returned

```
App.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
      var article = articles.findBy('id', params.article_id);
      console.log(article);
      return article;
   }
});
```

Directly invoking the child view URL is not working:

```
http://localhost/emberdata/#/articles/1
```

However clicking the link of articles, those child view route works:

```
this.resource('article', { path: ':article_id' });
```

This is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember.$.getJSON() will return a promise (see: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html). You can't call the findBy() method on a promise.

That being said, you're making it yourself very difficult. I recommend to start using the DS.RESTAdapter. In your case it would be something like this:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'emberdata/api'
});
```

then clear (or remove) ArticlesRoute because you will use convention (instead of configuration):

```
App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

idem for ArticleRoute. Except, if your backend doesn't support calls like /emberdata/api/article/1 use the following code:

```
App.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(params) {
      var article = this.store.find('article').findBy('id', params.article_id);
      console.log(article);
      return article;
   }
});
```

Comment: Clearing the ArticlesRoute? You mean removing the model retrieval. I try it. My table is empty

Comment: I already try using the RESTAdapter but it gives error - no model was found for 0. That is why I'm using the getJSON. It works to retrieve all articles. Howver the JSON is not searchables using findBy()